# JBoss 7.1.1 struts deployement problems

Tags: java, jboss, struts, jboss7.x

My application developed with struts, now I try to deploy under JBoss

but I see following errors

> 12:40:41,939 WARN  [org.jboss.as.ee] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBAS011006: Not installing optional component org.apache.struts.taglib.template.PutTag due to exception: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.struts.taglib.template.PutTag from [Module "deployment.backend.ear.frontend-war.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
>   at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:190) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]

and similar exceptions, seems it does not understand struts and his tags, but all libraries in the web-inf/lib folder. this is fully working application.

Struts version 1.3.8 > I am migrating project from JBoss 5 to JBoss 7.

have anyone similar problems?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I faced this issue during the Jboss7-upgrade and resolved it.

It was `struts-template.tld` file which referred to the `PutTag` under `org.apache.struts.taglib.template` but actually `PutTag` is under the path `org.apache.struts.taglib.tiles`.

Hence change the following in `struts-template.tld` file or if it is present in other `tld`-files.

From

```
<tagclass>org.apache.struts.taglib.template.PutTag</tagclass>
```

To

```
<tagclass>org.apache.struts.taglib.tiles.PutTag</tagclass>
```

Comment: thanks for contribution, your answer was poorly [formatted](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help). Please format your next post properly.

Comment: thanks, helped me to resolve my problem.  I faced this issue when integrating the struts1 app with Crystal Report 2016.

Answer (score 0):

Problem could be with your .tld files. They are expected to be placed under WEB-INF/tld directory of your .war file. 
Also try placing your libraries under ear/lib, also please share the directory structure of you deployment and share the complete error stack trace